# ZF2 - No element by the name of .. found in Form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

My zend framework 2 project concerns an online restaurant Menu and I am trying to make a form to add Pizzas to database. But something is wrong with my code. The form won't show up, instead this error shows up:

> No element by the name of [pizza_name] found in form

Please help me to find what's wrong with my code.

Here are my files:

addPizzaForm.php:

```
<?php 
namespace Pizza\Form;
use Zend\Form\Form; 
use Pizza\Form\AddPizzaForm;
use Pizza\Model\Pizza;

class AddPizzaForm extends Form 
{
public function construct() { 
parent:: construct('addpizzaform'); 
$this->add(array(
      'name' => 'pizza_name',
      'type' => 'text',
      'options' => array(label => 'Pizza name')));
$this->add(array(
      'name' => 'ingredients',
      'type' => 'textarea',
      'options' => array(label => 'Ingredients')));
$this->add(array(
      'name' => 'small_price',
      'type' => 'text',
      'options' => array(label => 'Small price')));

$this->add(array(
      'name' => 'big_price',
      'type' => 'text',
      'options' => array(label => 'Big price')));

$this->add(array(
      'name' => 'family_price',
      'type' => 'text',
      'options' => array(label => 'Family price')));

$this->add(array(
      'name' => 'party_price',
      'type' => 'text',
      'options' => array(label => 'Party price')));

$this->add(array(
      'name' => 'add_pizza',
      'type' => 'submit',
      'attributes' => array(
                            'value' => 'Add New Pizza',
                            'id' => 'submitbutton')));
    }
}
```

add.phtml view:

```
<?php
echo $this->headTitle('Add new Pizza');
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8"> <h1> Add new Pizza </h1>
</div>

<?php

$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('pizza',array('action'=>'add')));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formRow($form->get('pizza_name')) . "</br>";
echo $this->formRow($form->get('ingredients')) . "</br>";
echo $this->formRow($form->get('small_price')) . "</br>";
echo $this->formRow($form->get('big_price')) . "</br>";
echo $this->formRow($form->get('family_price')) . "</br>";
echo $this->formRow($form->get('party_price')) . "</br>";
echo $this->formRow($form->get('add_pizza')) . "</br>";
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
?>
```

PizzaController.php:

```
<?php

namespace Pizza\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Pizza\Form\AddPizzaForm;
use Pizza\Model\Pizza;

class PizzaController extends AbstractActionController { 

protected $pizzaTable;

public function addAction() 
{
    $add_form = new AddPizzaForm(); 
    $request = $this->getRequest(); 
    if($request->isPost()) 
    { 
        $pizza = new Pizza();
        $add_form->setInputFilter($pizza->getInputFilter());
        $add_form->setData($request->getPost()); 

        if($form->isValid())
        { 
            $pizza->exchangeArray($form->getData()); 
            $this->getPizzaTable()->save($pizza); 
        }

        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('pizza');
    }

    return array('form' => $add_form); 

} 

public function getPizzaTable() 
{ 
    if( !$this->pizzaTable) 
    { 
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator(); 
        $this->pizzaTable = $sm->get('Pizza\Model\PizzaTable');
    }
    return $this->pizzaTable; 
} 

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

You're getting that strange errors because there are **FOUR** important details that needs attention.

**A -** Your `construct()` method in `AddPizzaForm` has wrong name and signature. You have to rename `construct` to `__construct` change contents something like below:

```
class AddPizzaForm extends Form 
{    
    public function __construct($name = null, $options = array() )
    {
        $formName = is_null($name) ? 'addpizza-form' : $name;
        parent::__construct($formName, $options);
    }

}
```

**B -** Create an `init()` method in your form and add your form elements inside that. This detail is clearly stated in [official documentation](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html#creating-custom-elements):

> If you are creating your form class by extending Zend\Form\Form, you
>   must not add the custom element in the __construct but rather in the init() method.

So, in your case:

```
class AddPizzaForm extends Form 
{    
    // constructor etc..

    public function init()
    {
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'pizza_name',
            'type' => 'text',
            'options' => array(label => 'Pizza name')
            )
        );

        // ... add other for elements ...
    }

}
```

**C.** Finally, in your controller, you're trying to instantiate your form manually:

```
$add_form = new AddPizzaForm();
```

This is also bad practice. You need to get your `AddPizzaForm` instance from ServiceManager. This detail also stated in documentation:

> You must not directly instantiate your form class, but rather get an
>   instance of it through the Zend\Form\FormElementManager.

To do that, introduce your `AddPizzaForm` in `module.config.php` like below:

```
'form_elements' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'add-pizza-form' => 'Pizza\Form\AddPizzaForm',
    )
)
```

And grab it in your controller like this:

```
$add_form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('FormElementManager')->get('add-pizza-form');
```

**D -** The last thing is; *please read most of the [documentation](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) first* before making some experiments. Reading documentation is most important step to getting better in any language or framework.

Hope it helps. Happy coding!

Comment: nice and clean answer! the only point that i don't see as @foozy is the option **c**. it isn't bad practice to get your form not over the ``FormElementManager``. This is only an alternative method to request forms not over FCQN and call them with an shorter name.

Comment: Get your form class over the ``ServiceManager``, ``FormElementManager`` or simple ``new FormClass`` is totally fine. i prefer the ``new FormClass`` method because form element are often totaly different on different pages in validation requirements, so for readability i create them by myself and not over the ``ServiceManager``

Comment: @ins0, You're right but you can always modify validation group after grab the form instance. For example, `$form->setValidationGroup('name');` or `$form->setValidationGroup('name', 'email', 'password');` etc.. I think more justifications needed rather than *different validation requirements* to create form instance manually.

Comment: @foozy yeah i mean more that way ``$form->setInputfilter()`` not validation groups, but as i said this is more personal preferences